# Is it correct to use memory_order_relaxed at this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic

Is it correct to use `std::memory_order_relaxed` at the following code?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> counter(0);

    constexpr size_t thread_count = 10;
    std::array<std::thread, thread_count> threads;
    for (auto& th : threads) {
        th = std::thread([&counter]() {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
/*1*/           counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            }
        });
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

/*2*/ std::cout << counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have a method call counter. It doesn't matter when the counter will be actually incremented (`/*1*/`), it's enough if it will be incremented some time.
But when I call `atomic::load` (`/*2*/`), all counter changes that have been made should be visible.

Is it correct to use `std::memory_order_relaxed` in lines `/*1*/` and `/*2*/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. The thread joining provides the necessary synchronization point that ensures that the final `load()` sees the correct value.

Comment: Thanks! If I replaces `th.join()` by `std::this_thread::sleep_for(some long period of time)`, will be this code still correct? Or I should use at least `counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`?

Comment: @york.beta: No. You must have a synchronization point, e.g. a release/acquire pair. (The program wouldn't be *incorrect* as such, since you're *only* accessing an atomic variable, but the result would be unpredictable.) Then again, without joining, the state of the counter would be unpredictable anyway.

Comment: I had the same question and the same comment to the answer. Thanks @Kerrek SB ! Here is another one: Would a counter.fetch_add(0, std::memory_order_relaxed); to read counter achieve the same as having synchronization points through the join()s?

Comment: The rationale is here: stackoverflow.com/a/8833218/643011 "The only way to guarantee you have the "latest" value is to use a read-modify-write operation such as exchange(), compare_exchange_strong() or fetch_add()"
But then again the whole question would be pointless because however likely it is not guaranteed in which order the threads are scheduled and the writers are really finished. Even if it's a really long sleep.